# jquery .html returns undefined

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have ajax post which posts website to php which then returns it and I am using jquery to find and return element text.  This is working form some elements but not all and I dont understand why.  For the body meta and title tags it is returning undefined.  Is it my php or ajax post?

jquery/ajax

```
var dataString = name;
        //alert (dataString);return false;

            $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "senddom.php",
      data: {"dataString" : dataString },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(response) {
   var gdom = response;
  $('body').append("<p> contents of title:" + $(response).find('Title').html()+ "</p>");          
  $('body').append("<p> contents of meta:" + $(response).find('meta').html()+ "</p>");      
  $('body').append("<p> contents of all: " + $(response).find('body').html() + "</p>");

 $(response).find('p').each(function() {
  $('body').append("<p> contents of p: " + $(this).html() + "</p>");
});
```

my php

```
<?php 
    $site= $_POST['dataString'];             // get data
function curl_get($site){
    $useragent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$site);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,5);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent); 
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;

}

function getdom($site){
    $html = curl_get($site);
    // Create a new DOM Document
    $xml = new DOMDocument();
    @$xml->loadHTML($html);
   echo json_encode($html);
}

echo getdom($site);
?>
```

Comment: Have you observed the request / repsonse using something like Firebug's console?

Answer (score 4):

Your AJAX call is expecting JSON data in response to the request, so the `response` variable in your `success` callback will be an object of some kind. You can't pass a regular object to the jQuery function, it's not designed to handle it.

Use the object as you would any other, using either the dot - `object.property` - or square bracket - `object["property"]` - notations. Or change your server-side code so it returns a usable format (HTML or XML) instead of JSON.

Comment: I changed the data type in ajax post to html and changed the php echo json_encode($html) to just echo ($html) but its still not working.  I have only started learning php so still don't understand it much.